# While fetching data and storing it into sqlite db the UI of my app freezes

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-room

Hello My app is freezes ui for some seconds while it is fetching data from network and stores it in db and then shows it in recyclerview. For fetching data from network I am using retrofit and for storing it and fetching form db Room library. Both with the help of MVVM pattern. Is there a way to remoove the UI freeze?
Here is my code:

In the Mainactivity when clicking download btn

```
downloadBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> 
  eventsViewModel.insertEvents(this));
```

Viewmodel class:

```
public void insertEvents(Context context){

        final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        String token = preferences.getString("token", "");

        final Map<String,String> queryData = new HashMap<>();
        queryData.put("token", token);
        Call<EventsResponse> call = RetrofitClient.getmInstance().getApi().getEvents(queryData);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<EventsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<EventsResponse> call, Response<EventsResponse> response) {

                if (response.code() == 401){


                    String email = preferences.getString("email", "");
                    String password = preferences.getString("password", "");

                    Call<LoginResponse> call1 = RetrofitClient.getmInstance().getApi().loginuser(email, password);
                    call1.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                            if (response.code() == 200){

                                SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context); // 0 - for private mode
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                                editor.putString("token", response.body().getToken());
                                editor.apply();

                                insertEvents(context);

                            }
                            else {

                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                        }
                    });
                }

                if (response.code() == 200){
                    eventList = response.body().getData();

                    EventsTable eventsTable = new EventsTable();

                    TicketDatesTable ticketDatesTable = new TicketDatesTable();

                    for (int i = 0; i < eventList.size(); i++) {

                        eventsTable.setEvent_id(eventList.get(i).getId());
                        eventsTable.setTitle_tk(eventList.get(i).getTitle_tk());
                        eventsTable.setTitle_ru(eventList.get(i).getTitle_ru());
                        eventsTable.setImageURL("https://bilettm.com/" + eventList.get(i).getImage_url());
                        eventsTable.setStart_date(eventList.get(i).getStart_date());
                        eventsTable.setEnd_date(eventList.get(i).getEnd_date());
                        eventsTable.setSales_volume(eventList.get(i).getEnd_date());
                        eventsTable.setOrganiser_fees_volume(eventList.get(i).getOrganiser_fees_volume());
                        eventsTable.setViews(eventList.get(i).getViews());
                        eventsTable.setSales_volume(eventList.get(i).getSales_volume());
                        eventsTable.setIs_live(eventList.get(i).getIs_live());

                        if (!eventList.get(i).getTicket_dates().isEmpty()) {

                            showTimeList = eventList.get(i).getTicket_dates();
                            int b = 0;
                            while (b < showTimeList.size()) {
                                ticketDatesTable.setEvent_id(showTimeList.get(b).getEvent_id());

                                ticketDatesTable.setTicket_date(showTimeList.get(b).getTicket_date());

                                insertTicketDates(ticketDatesTable);

                                try {

                                    Thread.sleep(150);

                                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

                                }


                                b++;
                            }

                        }
                        insert(eventsTable);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(150);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<EventsResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }

public void insert(EventsTable data){
        repository.insertEvents(data);
    }

    public void insertTicketDates(TicketDatesTable ticketDatesTable){
        repository.insertTicketDates(ticketDatesTable);
```

Here is my repository :

```
public void insertEvents(EventsTable data){
    new EventInsertion(eventsDAO).execute(data);
}
private static class EventInsertion extends AsyncTask<EventsTable, Void, Void> {

    private EventsDAO eventsDAO;

    private EventInsertion(EventsDAO eventsDAO) {
        this.eventsDAO = eventsDAO;
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(EventsTable... eventsTables) {
        eventsDAO.insertEvents(eventsTables[0]);

        return null;
    }
}

public void insertTicketDates(TicketDatesTable data){
    new TicketDatesInsertion(eventsDAO).execute(data);
}
private static class TicketDatesInsertion extends AsyncTask<TicketDatesTable, Void, Void> {

    private EventsDAO eventsDAO;

    private TicketDatesInsertion(EventsDAO eventsDAO) {
        this.eventsDAO = eventsDAO;
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(TicketDatesTable... ticketDatesTables) {
        eventsDAO.insertTicketDates(ticketDatesTables[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is my DAO:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertEvents(EventsTable data);

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertTicketDates(TicketDatesTable datesTable);
```

I think it freezes when it is storing it into sqlite db

Comment: Use Asynctask or a thread for processing data.

Comment: @Chandankushwaha in my viewmodel?? I am already using asynctask in repo for inserting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem. It was initializing entity before starting for loop:

BEFORE:

```
EventsTable eventsTable = new EventsTable();

for (int i = 0; i < eventList.size(); i++) {
       INSERT();

     }
```

AFTER:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < eventList.size(); i++) {
             EventsTable eventsTable = new EventsTable();
             INSERT();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to collect all your required objects in an `ArrayList` and then pass it on to the `AsyncTask` and from there to `DAO` for bulk insertion.

And remove all Thread.sleep(150) statements as they serve no purpose.

Comment: I tried removing thread.sleep() and inserted directly the list of items. But it inserts only the last item of list

Comment: I used thread sleep to insert one item and wait and then insert the next

Comment: without this it only inserts one item

Comment: Please share the code in which u tried to insert the items in the form of a list and removed `Thread.sleep()`.

Comment: If u consider it appropriate, please share ur solution for the benefit of all.

Comment: i shared it I have alrady answered my question. It was a stupid problem

Answer (score -1):

why you are using this Thread.sleep(150);Call is already a background task in retrofit

Comment: Without using it it only stores the last item into room. If I delay 150ms it will inserrt every item. I thought that it will freeze the UI but not like this

Comment: @Chandankushwaha I know it

Comment: if I wont wait 150ms at the end of loop it can not insert all the data